# Chaining joins tables in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to join multiple tables together and then make a query but I'm running into a syntax error.

I have the following tables:

```
achievement_standards
  id
  description

terms
  start_date
  end_date
  term_year_id

term_standards
  term_id
  achievement_standard_id
```

And I have the following method:

```
def school_standards
  @standards = @school.achievement_standards
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN term_standards ON achievement_standards.id = term_standards.achievement_standard_id")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN terms ON terms.id = term_standards.term_id")
  .where("term_standards.id IS ? OR (term_standards.term_id IS NOT ? AND terms.term_year_id IS NOT ?)", nil, nil, 100),

end
```

I'm getting a `syntax error at or near "100"`. Is there something wrong with how I joined the tables? I'm trying to get achievement standards that are not in the `term_standards` table or ones that are not in the `term_year` 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of your query :

```
... AND terms.term_year_id IS NOT ?
```

When given param `100`, this will expand as :

```
... AND terms.term_year_id IS NOT 100
```

This is not valid SQL : `IS` is not to compare a value with a number, for this you would need to use the (in)equality operator. You probably want :

```
... AND terms.term_year_id <> ?
```

---

More generally speaking : in most RDBMS, `IS` is only used in conjonction with `NULL` (either `IS NULL`, or `IS NOT NULL`). So basically this type of parameterized expressions can only be used with a `NULL` parameter (that is, the RDBMS will raise an error if passed another value) :

```
term_standards.id IS ?
term_standards.term_id IS NOT ?
```

Depending on your purpose, either you don't need to use parameters (make the `?` explicitly `NULL` in your query), or you might want to refactor your query.

Comment: Understood, I'll keep that in mind regarding these operators!